# does latest chromedriver 2.33 needs selenium 3

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am using Selenium 2.52 and chromedriver 2.29 for chrome browser version 57.

But I could see chrome browser version got updated to latest version 61 in selenium nodes and so tests are failing with "org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: Element is not clickable
".

So I have updated the chromedriver version to latest 2.33 since the Chrome browser version is the latest.
some tests are getting passed and still, I could see some tests are failing with same error or similar type of error.

Is it required to update Selenium version to any latest version or Selenium 3 to use latest chromedriver?

Comment: Check for `IsClickable` property and then try to click it. In many cases., giving some `sleep` time after the page is loaded solved this problem.(workaround)

Answer (score 0):

Your selenium version is an old version. With the latest "browser"driver (ChromeDriver 2.33, in your case) is recommended to use **Selenium 3.5 (and greater)**